# python:extract certain part of string

Tags: python

I have a string from which I would like to extract certain part. The string looks like :

```
 E:/test/my_code/content/dir/disp_temp_2.hgx
```

This is a path on a machine for a specific file with extension hgx

I would exactly like to capture "disp_temp_2". The problem is that I used strip function, does not work for me correctly as there are many '/'. Another problem is that, that the above location will change always on the computer.

Is there any method so that I can capture the exact string between the last '/' and '.'

My code looks like:

```
path = path.split('.')
```

.. now I cannot split based on the last '/'.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the os.path module:

```
import os.path
filename = "E:/test/my_code/content/dir/disp_temp_2.hgx"
name = os.path.basename(filename).split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Depends on what the user wants. The code above will turn something like `foo.tar.gz` into `foo`. This seems like the desired behavior. If someone has multiple dots in a filename like `my.cool.file.txt` then the convention becomes ambiguous and cannot be parsed without domain specific knowledge.

Comment: Thanks this works perfect for me. The file name that we has always one dot. That is before the extension.

Answer (score 3):

Python comes with the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module, which gives you much better tools for handling paths and filenames:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> p = "E:/test/my_code/content/dir/disp_temp_2.hgx"
>>> head, tail = os.path.split(p)
>>> tail
'disp_temp_2.hgx'
>>> os.path.splitext(tail)
('disp_temp_2', '.hgx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard libs are cool:

```
>>> from os import path
>>> f = "E:/test/my_code/content/dir/disp_temp_2.hgx"
>>> path.split(f)[1].rsplit('.', 1)[0]
'disp_temp_2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path=path.rsplit('/',1)[1].split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`path = path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split on the other part :

```
path = path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
```